# How to compress directory in AWS S3 bucket using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to zip a file(object) in AWS S3 cloud storage using .Net C# also is it possible to compress a file(object) in S3 with any of the API provided by AWS SDK for .net

Comment: And.. What would you like us to do?

Comment: So you need to compress a folder or bucket from Amazon S3 to zip file?

Comment: Yes Gopi c.s, I want to compress my folder and its sub folder in to single zip  to reduce downloading time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello unfortunately there is no method or api for any platfom to zip an existing file in S3
instead You would need to create the zip by getting objects from S3, then putting the zip file back to S3.

you can check this which is helpful to create your own api - http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-custom-events.html

So you can build the functionality to zip files in S3 using JavaScript and run it from Lambda
It shows how to configure an S3 event. So when an object is put into the bucket, S3 will invoke the Lambda function that you create

Answer (score 0):

I have written AWS Lambda service which can create *.zip using json params like [{bucket, key}]. But I've bumped into Lambda memory restriction. In fact you can create .zip only from ~250MB input. It takes ~22sec. So, if you have little input - Lambda is a great approach! Otherwise - use C#(complete download or stream - it' up to you!)
Also, you should be aware that Lambda doesn't work with Blob objects - use JSZip

Comment: Did you publish that zipping function anywhere? Would like to take a look.

Comment: Maksim do you have any sample code or pointers to how to achieve this?